# Maintaining a dynamic MySQL table with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, database

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns:

```
MySQL db table
+--+----+-------------+
|id|data|display_order|
+--+----+-------------+
|0 |0   |2            |
+--+----+-------------+
|1 |1   |1            |
+--+----+-------------+
|2 |1   |2            |
+--+----+-------------+
|3 |1   |3            |
+--+----+-------------+
|4 |1   |4            |
+--+----+-------------+
|5 |1   |5            |
+--+----+-------------+
```

That generates divs in HTML using PHP:

```
HTML generated from DB:
<div>
    Div From id 1
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 2
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 3
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 4
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 5
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<button>Add Div</button>
<button>Update DB</button>
```

And the generated divs can then be changed with JavaScript by pressing the Add or Remove Div buttons above:

```
HTML changed:
 <div>
    Div From id 1
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    New Div 1
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 2
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 4
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    Div From id 5
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<div>
    New Div 2
    <button>Remove Div</button>
</div>
<button>Add Div</button>
<button>Update DB</button>
```

Once the divs are changed in the HTML, and it's time to update the database (by pressing "Update DB"), how can I update the database properly? I only want to update the database when the update button is pressed, and I need to know what to update, what to insert, and what to delete. I also want to update the display order to reflect the added or removed divs.

My instinct was to put the table id's and display orders in hidden fields in my HTML divs, but I'm not sure if that would be safe to do, would that be a security risk of some kind? I'm not really sure how to proceed, would anyone mind giving me some advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What php mysql connection are you using? mysqli, PDO..? You're right about the hidden fields. They won't be tampered with. Especially if you validate the information being posted to the php script.

Comment: PDO, it seems much more secure and robust than mysql or mysqli. Do you mean that I'm right about the hidden fields being OK to use, or that they'd be a risk?

Comment: why dont use checkbox?

Comment: Use a checkbox for what?

Comment: in a form.. to select what id remove..

Comment: My requirement is for it to be more dynamic; the form needs to be immediately dynamic from the GUI side. Not my choice unfortunately. That would be easier, though. :)

Comment: It seems you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Have you tried phpMyAdmin to see if it meets your needs?

Comment: How would phpMyAdmin help? I thought it was just for DB maintenance, not a program you can use with production code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't do this.

The security vulnerabilities would occur in the PHP file that you are posting to in order to modify the database. Ensure that requests can only come from the local IP, and pass in the div IDs to be added and removed, along with the orders to the script. Ensure that you aren't passing the data straight into the database from the POST request.

Maintain the state of the page locally, perhaps with a poll for updated data on a low frequency.

Comment: I didn't think of that. So, keeping a dynamic list of the visible divs in a hidden field would be safe, as long as I validated that list in PHP?

Comment: I don't see why not. I mean, the information is in front of the user anyway, so I don't see how it would introduce a security problem.

It's worth googling "SQL injection" and related security issues in PHP. There are a lot of gotchas which occur when you are just learning PHP which will turn into security issues for you later on.

Comment: And to add to Seth's comment above, use PHP PDO instead of the default mysql_query.